# Addressing rust behind Shower Valve

Tags: plumbing, shower

My parent's informed me that their basement shower had been giving them issues. The valve was leaking and caused the metal behind it to rust. I found a local place that can reassemble the shower valve and fix the leak or I found the parts online to DIY it, but I'm worried about the rust. I'm handy but not a plumber. I'm a little confused as to what the metal is, but my guess is a plaster guard due to it being a cinder block wall.

Is this metal piece replaceable or at the least able to be mended?

Thank you for any help!
[image]

Comment: Just confirming whether parts of it are cortoded away, or is it just discoloured.

Comment: There is a hole in the rust and it's very brittle.